# How to pause a game using C#

Tags: c#

How do you pause a game using C#? I want to know the functionality part of it. I am trying to combine a while true loop with a Boolean variable. at any time the Boolean turns false , it will cause a continue statement on the while loop. with my current knowledge, i can only achieve a continue statement at certain points in the game.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WhileLoop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool play = true;

            while (true)
            {
                play = true;

                if (play)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Do something1");

                    play = false;

                    if (!play)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Do something2");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Do something3");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define what you expect to happen when paused

Comment: And how should it be paused at all, where is the user interaction?

Comment: `continue` might sound like "unpause" but it has nothing to do with it - it just immediately starts the next iteration of the `while` block

Comment: Describe in more detail what you want to achieve. More details about the game itself, and how it will interact with the user.

Comment: It really isn't so much about the user interaction and the game. I am just curious as if there is a mechanism that causes a continue on a while true loop at any certain point in the code when the Boolean play turns false.

Comment: What you are describing is both simple and complex depending on the  nature of what you are trying to acheive (which is still unknown). What you have now is just a simple single threaded workfkow, yes you can continue on that but it wouldn't make much difference whether the while loop is continuously evaluating or is stopped waiting for use input

Answer (score 1):

You may want to build your game with a State Machine. With this structure you can set a current state in your game (like Menu, Game, Pause, Exit) and run your code accordingly. It is important that you do not use `Thread.sleep` or something like this since the program will simply not respond with these commands.

Useful tutorials for these mechanics are all over the place like here: http://lazyfoo.net/articles/article06/index.php

I generally recommend having a look at the SDL tutorials from http://lazyfoo.net

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned game I guess its game related? Normally games have a time scale. 1.0 is realtime. 
You then have a deltaTime between each frame. Everything that is time dependant uses this factor. `var movement = direction*deltaTime`. If you pause the game you set time scale to 0